# Need notification of applicationWillUnhide

Tags: cocoa, macos, osx-lion

I'm using Lion, and the applicationWillUnhide - applicationDidUnhide application delegate methods are not being called when expected.

I'm miniaturizing the app to the doc, and then clicking on the dock icon again, but they are not being called, and the application is being deminiaturized correctly.

Maybe this does not count as hiding? How can I catch this event?
Your help is greatly appreciated,
Jose.

Comment: Did the provided answer solve your problem? If not, please be more explicit about what you mean by _miniaturizing the app to the Dock_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t minimise an application on OS X, only hide it. To observe your `NSApplication`’s hidden state use `NSApplicationDidHideNotification` and `NSApplicationWillUnhideNotification`. If these notifications don’t appear to be sent correctly, you’ll need to show us some code.

Or do you actually mean minimising windows? You’ll have to observe `NSWindowWillMiniaturizeNotification`/`NSWindowDidMiniaturizeNotification` and `NSWindowDidDeminiaturizeNotification` for that (as per the [NSWindow class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html)). Remember that you can pass `nil` for the object parameter of `-[NSNotification addObserver:selector:name:object:]` to observe the minimisation state of all your application’s windows.